# UTF 8 Encoding with Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, utf-8

i need to store Malayalam font which is not in utf 8 encoding, am having a bulk of data in excel which is having lots of Malayalam in it,inserted using athira font but when i convert that into csv file i cannot read the data in those excel files so if i insert those data to MySQL db readability problem occurs

> Is there a way to convert that as utf 8(i tried saving as text file and again saving it as utf 8--->csv but dint worked)
>
> can i insert those files as readable in my sql db using some Collation??
> please help if any one knows !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing Malyalam text in a MySQL table specify a Unicode encoding either for your table or the entire schema. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html for available encodings.
Generally it is always a good advise to go with Unicode encoding if you have text in more than one language or a language (like malyalam) that does not have an ANSI code page. See http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html for more details about UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to upload the same into google drive and open it through google sheet!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).